# clip padding while scrolling on list view in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I have used `clipToPadding` in android to clip the padding while scrolling horizontally and vertically. Is there any specific attribute like clipToPadding in flutter? The behavior would look alike:

[image]

```
   ListView.separated(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
          width: 8,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Text(data[index].name);
        },
        itemCount: data.length,
      )
```

Comment: Could you please provide any example code? If you want a Scrollable to have clipped paddings - you just wrap it with a Padding.

Comment: @Thepeanut What if you don't want the children clipped to the padding? That's what setting false to `clipToPadding` in android does.

Comment: @SIMMORSAL then padding in the ListView itself is enough. The scroll area will have paddings that will not crop the children while scrolling. It will be used more like an offset while scrolling.

Comment: @Thepeanut So then the answer to this question would be changing `padding: EdgeInsets.all(16)` to something like this `EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, top 16, bottom: 16)`, because in android giving padding to the equivalent of ListView actually clips the content, and giving it `clipToPadding=false` will show the content

Comment: @SIMMORSAL I'm not a native android developer, so not sure about the clipToPadding parameter, but yeah, if you want the scrollview to have paddings that do not crop their children - it's the padding param, if you want a padding that will clip the children, then it's a padding around the scrollview widget itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a native android dev, but if I did understand right the "clipToPadding" option, you just want to remove padding from the ListView and add padding around it.

```dart
Container(
              height: 100.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              child: ListView.separated(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
                  width: 8,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 1.0,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                      child: Center(child: Text(index.toString())),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: 20,
              ),
            ),
```

OR using Container (it's just to set max height for the listview) + separate Padding:

```dart
Container(
              height: 100.0,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: ListView.separated(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
                    width: 8,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 1.0,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                        child: Center(child: Text(index.toString())),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You only used padding of listView:

```
return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemCount: snapshot.data!.results!.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ItemSearch(
            onClick: () {}, movie: snapshot.data!.results![index]);
      });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).